# Which ASPNetCore packages are compatible with netcoreapp2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops

I got the following from Nuget restore at Azure DevOps Pipeline.

What packages are compatible with netcoreapp2.1?

```
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor 2.1.0 supports:
  - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.0 supports:
  - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression 2.1.0 supports:
  - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
  - portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=wp8+netcore45+net45+wp81+wpa81)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.0 supports:
  - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
```

I use implicit versioning for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

The relevant parts of my CSPROJ file are the following.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>true</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29820 -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisablePackageAssetsCache>true</DisablePackageAssetsCache>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="graphiql" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Linq" Version="4.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The following is for azure-pipelines.yaml.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: "NuGet use 4.3.0"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.3.0

- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.1.504'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "NuGet Restore"
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET build"
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET publish package"
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/pkg'
```

Full log output of Nuget Restore is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonasarcangel/Misc-Issues/master/Azure-Pipelines-Nuget-Restore-Issue).

Comment: Mind share your csproj (specifically the parts around runtime, targets and packages)? Are you using [implicit versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implicit-versioning) or explicit? And of course which build task are you using? The .NET Core ones?  Or the old msbuild ones

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That's exactly what implicit version is intended to fix (and provide automatic hotfixing rollforward packages on portable apps / latest on the OS during build time for self-contained apps), so you automatically roll forward

Comment: Where did this error come from? `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` for example is a .NET Standard 2.0 package. It should work just fine with any .NET Core version that supports .NET Standard 2.0, ie 2.0 and later

Comment: @Tseng I deleted that comment because the packages in this question are Standard 2.0. They just work with .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: @JonasArcangel *all* of those packages are compatible, in fact, many of those are added by default by the built-in .NET Core project templates. Is the correct .NET Core SDK installed on your build agent?

Comment: [This issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312728/build-restore-failed-with-aspnet-core-web-api-netc.html) containes the same errors. It appears that NuGet 4.3 had to be installed explicitly through a Pipeline step, at least back in October 2018

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Well the 2.x templates reference only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` (recommended) or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (soon to be deprecated). As for the op: Yea provide as much information as possible. Do you use hosted build agents or private build agents (hosted within your company)?

Comment: Why are you mixing ASP.NET Core 2.1 with explicit ASP.NET Core 2.2 dependencies?

Comment: The 2.2 dependencies were added after 'dotnet restore' complained that I should putting that explicitly. So maybe there is some library perhaps that is confusing it.

Comment: I have taken out the 2.2 dependencies and tried using NuGet 4.3 in my YAML but I still see the same errors. I'll try focusing on getting the YAML right.

Comment: I added the output of the Nuget Restore step. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonasarcangel/Misc-Issues/master/Azure-Pipelines-Nuget-Restore-Issue

Comment: Tried updating to netcoreapp2.2, but still getting similar issues. It chose Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1. https://github.com/jonasarcangel/Misc-Issues/blob/master/Azure-Pipelines-Nuget-Restore-Issue-aspnetcore2.2